# Sorting decimals

Tags: bash, list, sorting, decimal

here is another question for sorting a list with decimals:

```
$ list="1 2 5 2.1"
$ for j in "${list[@]}"; do echo "$j"; done | sort -n
1 2 5 2.1
```

I expected

```
1 2 2.1 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to `"${list[@]}"` but just `$list` because it is just a string. Otherwise it gets all numbers in the same field.

```
$ for j in $list; do echo $j; done | sort -n
1
2
2.1
5
```

With your previous code it was not sorting at all:

```
$ list="77 1 2 5 2.1 99"
$ for j in "${list[@]}"; do echo "$j"; done | sort -n
77 1 2 5 2.1 99
```

Comment: He doesn't need `${list[@]}` at all, because `list` is a simple string, not an array.

Comment: Oh I was so much into the array way. Now I see, just updated my answer @chepner.

Comment: In addition, you have to set the locale in such a way that numerical data that uses a decimal point is sorted correctly, otherwise you get the same problem as in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812914/sorting-a-list-with-multi-part-items/). If you use, e.g., `LC_ALL=de_DE`, then `.` is interpreted as a thousands separator, rather than a decimal point, and `2.1` is interpreted as `21` and sorted accordingly. Use `export LC_ALL=C` before you run `sort -n`.

Answer (score 4):

If you intended that the variable `list` be an array, then you needed to say:

```
list=(1 2 5 2.1)
```

which would result in

```
1
2
2.1
5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for j in $list; do echo $j; done | sort -n
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' $list|sort -n
```